# Redirect Url for Windows Application using OAuth2

Tags: oauth-2.0

I'm testing some social API using OAuth2 and facing a problem with redirect url, my application is using an embedded browser to get access token from server and redirect url to `http://localhost`, it worked fine on my computer, but if other user's computers don't have any web server installed, how should I set the redirect url, and how can I make my application listen to the access token instead of copy and paste it back manually ?

Any help will be appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't necessarily need a webserver. You could register a fictitious `redirect_uri` in your STS and then configure your hosted WebBrowser *listen* for a redirect to this url and extract the `access_token` from the fragment portion of the url that the STS will send. The response from the STS will look like this:

```
http://fictitious.com/#access_token=some_token&token_type=bearer&expires_in=3600
```

So in order to implement the [implicit grant flow](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-4.2) there are 2 steps:

1. You direct the hosted WebBrowser to the authorization endpoint of your STS: `http://sts.com/authorize?client_id=CLIENT_ID&response_type=token&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Ffictitious.com%2F`
2. The user authenticates against the STS and is redirected back to the fictitious url that was provided as `redirect_uri` in the first step.
3. You intercept the redirect to this url and extract the `access_token` from it.